# Kotlin: Why it's additional 1 is being counted in sum variable?

Tags: loops, kotlin

```
object GrassHopper {
    var sum = 0
  fun summation(n:Int):Int {
    for (i in 1..n){
        sum=sum+i
    }
      return sum
  }

}
```

Now, the first test case is Grasshopper.summation(1) -- Result is 1 and this test case is passed.
And, the second test case is Grasshopper.summation(8) -- Result is 36 and in this case, my result is 37.

So, for the second testcase why my result is 37 instead of 36?

Comment: You are using the same object instance between the tests. If you ran the second test without running the first one, it would be 36. You aren't resetting `sum` between tests

Comment: Got it, I declared var in function instead of object. It worked. Thanks!